# Why doesn't the Ask! framework provide any "overflow protection"?

Tags: ink

In the Ask! framework documentation [here](https://ask-lang.github.io/ask-docs/ask-vs-ink) it says Ask! doesn't provide any "overflow protection", whereas ink! does, but it doesn't explain why. Why doesn't Ask! framework provide any "overflow protection"?

Comment: ink! is written in rust and rust provides `overflow/underflow protection`, that's why by default ink! support overflow protection. May be `AssemblyScript` which is used by Ask! doesn't support `overflow protection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in overflow protection doesn't exist in AssemblyScript as of now: https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/447.

You should be able to use a safe arithmetic library though.